# Angular reactive forms form-group validations are working only for any one row in Mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms, angular2-form-validation

I have Mat table with multiple rows, **with add button ,on click of it, adds a new row**. i want to add validations for all the rows ,right now my code below is taking a validation only for any one row.

my component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="auditUserValidation">
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

<ng-container matColumnDef="Audit">

<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
<mat-select formControlName="name" placeholder="Pls select">
<mat-option [value]="audit" *ngFor="let name of nameList">{{name.firstname}}</mat-option>
</mat-select></mat-cell>

</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="Country">

<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Country</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
<mat-select formControlName="Country" placeholder="Pls select">
<mat-option [value]="audit" *ngFor="let country of CountryList">{{country.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select></mat-cell>

</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>


Save button which i want to disable if all rows not selected

<button type="button" (click)="addElement()"> <i class="material-icons">add</i>Add</button>
<button type="button" [disabled]='auditUserValidation.invalid' (click)="submitReport()">Save</button>
```

my component.ts file

```
  auditUserValidation: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder }   
  ngOnInit() {
    this.auditUserValidation = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      Country: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
}
```

Comment: If possible then provide demo in the stackblitz

Comment: Ya sure i'll try providing same in stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you has a formArray. As always, we has a function that return a formGroup

```
createGroup(data:any)
  {
    data=data || {name:'',surname:''}
    return new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(data.name,Validators.required),
      surname: new FormControl(data.surname,Validators.required)
    })
  }
```

After create the formArray, we make the "dataSource" formArray.controls

```
  this.dataSource=this.myformArray.controls
```

So, the only is ask about

```
element.get('name').touched &&element.get('name').errors
```

e.g.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
       <input [formControl]="element.get('name')">
              <div *ngIf="element.get('name').touched 
                 && element.get('name').errors">required</div>
           </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Surname Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="surname">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Surname </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">

       <input [formControl]="element.get('surname')">
       <div *ngIf="element.get('surname').touched 
         && element.get('surname').errors">required</div>
       </td>
  </ng-container>
  <!--if we want delete the row (*)-->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = index;">
          <button mat-button (click)="remove(i)">delete</button>
       </td>
  </ng-container>


  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmfjhh-5fmwbp?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

**Updated** add and remove rows

(*) the `displayedColumns` becomes like

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['name','surname','delete'];
```

Two functions serve to add and remove rows

```
  add() {
    this.myformArray.push(this.createGroup(null));
    this.table.renderRows(); //<--see that we need refresh the table
  }
  remove(index: number) {
    this.myformArray.removeAt(index);
    this.table.renderRows();  //<--see that we need refresh the table
  }
```

where `table` is

```
  @ViewChild(MatTable, { static: false }) table: MatTable<any>;
```

Comment: Thanks Eliseo , i also have dynamic rows which will be added on click of add button how to handle that added row validation? now validators work only for one row.

Comment: I just updated the stackblitz to add rows (it's only `push(this.createGroup(null))` and use renderRow to refresh the table. It's equal: the control is who has the error. If you add a new row, and "touched" the control you can see the error

Comment: Thanks alot Eliseo , it's working perfectly fine, it would be much more better if you could update the code with delete row button on each row ,which deletes the same row.

Comment: You need add a new column to `displayedColumns`, and define the matCellDef like `*matCellDef="let i = index;"` to pass the number of the row. Just updated in stackblitz and in response

Answer (score 0):

You should add controls to the `FormGroup` in `addElement`method.
Something like:

```
addElement() {
 this. auditUserValidation.addControl('new', new FormControl('', Validators.required));
}
```

please take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eypxbq?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thanks nick, it seems this is not working for my scenario, can you tell me what's that 'new' string?

Comment: is it your control `formControlName` property. please check stackblitz

Comment: after adding in addElement method it's not working, i added formControlName  but it doesn't work for added row.